# SQL Server reporting server issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

A couple of days back we moved our SQL Server database from a Physical server to a VM based server.
There were some reports in the reporting database which we skipped. 
Now we cannot start the sql server instance on the old physical server, as the host name now points to the new vm based server in the DNS.
Can I just copy the reporting server database data and log files from the old server and attach them in the new server ? Would it work ?
Any help would be appreciated. Also if you can let me know of some steps it would be great.

Comment: I believe you should be able to copy over the `ldf` and `mdf` files.

Comment: Should I also copy the reportservertempdb data and log files ?

Answer (score 2):

Before doing anything backup your reporting services database and keys.

I would advice you to backup / restore the database to the new server rather than copying the mdf and ldf files. (report service must be stopped before restoring)

You should also export the encyption key from the old server and import it to the new server.

Also make sure to make the same customizations to the new report server configuration files if there are any (eg. custom dll permissions), copy custom dll's etc

By following the above steps you can make an SSRS database work on newer SSRS versions (I have tested restore an SSRS 2005 database to SSRS 2014 and 2016)

Read more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/moving-the-report-server-databases-to-another-computer-ssrs-native-mode

Comment: The issue i am facing is that the SQL Server instance on the report server whose database i am trying to move is not available as the machine's host name is currently pointing to the new server in the dns. We will need to change the host name on the old server. The sql server instance will not start after changing the host name. How else can I backup the encryption keys of the report server db i am trying to move ?

Comment: To make your old instance working you have to change your old server SSRS configuration to match your old server IP or DNS name. 1) In the rsreportserver.config change the InstanceId value 2) Edit the machine value in the keys table of the reportserver database